# GIf image is not animating

Tags: c#, gif

I have written the following code to upload different types of images.

```
public static void CompressImageWithNewDimensions(Stream stream, string targetPath, double fileSizeKB)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var image = Image.FromStream(stream))
            {
                double scaleFactor;
                if (fileSizeKB <= 900)
                {
                    scaleFactor = 0.9;
                }
                else if (fileSizeKB <= 1500)
                {
                    scaleFactor = 0.8;
                }
                else if (fileSizeKB <= 2000)
                {
                    scaleFactor = 0.7;
                }
                else
                {
                    scaleFactor = 0.3;
                }
                var newWidth = (int)(image.Width * scaleFactor);
                var newHeight = (int)(image.Height * scaleFactor);
                var CompressImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
                var CompressImageGraph = Graphics.FromImage(CompressImage);
                CompressImageGraph.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                CompressImageGraph.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                CompressImageGraph.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                var imageRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
                CompressImageGraph.DrawImage(image, imageRectangle);
                //CompressImage.Save(targetPath, image.RawFormat);                    
                CompressImage.Save(targetPath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif); 
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
```

Now I have successfully uploaded GIF file in my folder, but in the folder when I am opening the image, it is not animating.

Comment: My guess is because you haven't saved an animated GIF, but instead just a single static image.

Comment: @Abion47 so how can i do that? would you please give me some idea to do this?

Comment: I have no idea how to do it. What experience I have with working with GIF images within C# has taught me to avoid it if at all possible. I'd recommend Google, though - surely someone has figured it out by now.

Comment: The .NET gif encoder does not support saving animated images.  The GIF format got crippled after Unisys started to demand royalties for the patents they hold.  Widely ignored but a company like Microsoft can't get away with that.  You'll have to find a library, we already have lots of questions about that.